# convert all values of mixed types to array type in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

have a pandas dataframe column with mixed types as below

```
[], 'Traditional', ['Courtyard'], ['Contemporary', 'Florida', 'Patio']
```

I would like the string field to be enclosed in []

```
[], ['Traditional'], ['Courtyard'], ['Contemporary', 'Florida', 'Patio']
```

Tried:

```
new_col = df['architectural_style']

new_col = [ [x] if (type(x) == 'str') else x for x in new_col ]
```

but I get the below error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column ARCHITECTURAL_STYLE with type object')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is mixing dimensions and `type(x)=='str'` should be changed to `type(x)==str` and that must work.
or you might use isinstance. e.x

```
test = [[], 'Traditional', ['Courtyard'], ['Contemporary', 'Florida', 'Patio']]

new_col = [ [x] if isinstance(x,str) else x for x in test]
print(new_col)
```

And here is what you want

```
[[], ['Traditional'], ['Courtyard'], ['Contemporary', 'Florida', 'Patio']]
```